# Tomcat multipart form upload error with temp directory

Tags: java, tomcat

When I attempt to upload a form that contains an image and a regular form item, I get the following error :

org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /usr/tomcat7/tmp/upload__275a1dac_1371dd097cc__8000_00000001.tmp (No such file or directory)

It's failing on ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(request). I get no other information from a regular stacktrace.

This seems to only happen for files larger than about 5k (sort of a restrictive limit).

I have verified that the directory exists and is readable and writeable. There is plenty of disk space. I have tried changing the tmp directory, but get the same error for the changed directory. I have tried setting maxUploadSize in server.xml - to no effect.

I am using JQuery ajaxSubmit on the client side if it's relevant, but I've used it in the past without problem.

I'm at a loss and would appreciate pointers on what I can do, or at least what the best way would be to debug the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using the Streaming API ? That way a repository would not be necessary.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html

Comment: maxUploadSize is not a valid setting in Tomcat's server.xml

Comment: Since you appear (based on the file paths) to be using Tomcat 7, why not use the built-in file upload features of the Servlet 3.0 API?

Comment: Looks like there's better ways to accomplish this. Thanks for the tips!